# Restoring a copy of the backup directories

Tags: marklogic

I maintain a copy of the MarkLogic server created backup by initiating a daily sync job. The sync job is unilateral i.e. all the new/updated files of backup will be pushed to backup copy but the deleted files will still exist in backup copy. Now if I have to restore by 
deleting backup directory and pushing the backup copy to backup directory, will it affect the restore? I mean there will be files which will be redundant.

I sync on a daily basis at one particular time. Full backup is synced on weekly basis and increments are synced on daily basis.

Comment: @MichaelGardner - I'm syncing the backup directory using unix rsync command. In case of a restore I'd like to copy the backup and paste it again where ML stores the backup let's say /MLbackup.

Answer (score 1):

The MarkLogic backups are stored in time-stamp specific folders underneath the backup directory, and the incremental backups are also stored in a time-stamp directory based on the last full backup (which can be inside the same directory as the full backup).  As long as you are maintaining the same directory structure (which rsync should), then moving an archived copy of the backups back to the system for restoration should not be an issue.  Any perceived redundancies will be managed by the MarkLogic server during the restoration process.

[MarkLogic backup utility](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore) documentation.

As always, regular validation of backup/restore procedures should be done to ensure the process works.

Comment: You are misunderstanding. The backups are scheduled and maintained as per ML guide. I'm talking about copy of the backup using rsync process.

Comment: @bosari I clarified your question base on your comments, and updated my answer.